# Is there any way to check the id of a $_POST variable?

Tags: php

I need to distinguish two variables that are being passed from a form.  It is important that these two variables have the same name.  Because of this i have given them different ids (but it could be classes, it really doesn't matter in this application).  I just need to know if there is a way to look at a $_POST variable, and have PHP tell me what the ID was before it was lumped in to the array of values with the same name.

Comment: You will never get the HTML id or class of any elements.

Comment: Darn.  Is there anything else I can use to distinguish two items with the same name?

Comment: Why don't you give them unique names? What are you holding against unique names?

Comment: Basically in the program a user enters in questions, and a form is generated dynamically for them.  There are two types of questions, one kind that leads into another question, and one kind that leads to the end of the form.  Because they all have the same name of "question[]" it's really easy to loop through the big array that it spits out, but i just need to be able to distinguish between the two types of questions.

Comment: I think it's better to use two arrays. Just because it's easier with one big array doesn't mean it's appropriate for the meant use.

Comment: If I didn't use one big array I would literally have to undo around 50 hours of work.  Are you sure there isn't any other way?

Comment: Well, the question is how did you get to 50 hours work with one loop for one array? I don't know any other way than using two different names/levels. You could use `question[end][]` and `question[next][]` but that's about the same using two unique names. Try with using a multi-dimensional array if that's better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friendly user in an irc chat recommended that I use a multidimensional array where every time I loop through it I am greeted with another array where I can check for the key name.  The key name can just be the id that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two different form fields with the same name if you create an array for the name, such as:

```
<input type="text" name="category[]" value="red" />
<input type="text" name="category[]" value="blue" />
```

Then when you've posted the form values you can examine the $_POST value with var_dump(), such as:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

And you can then retrieve the values from the array.